Columns reconciliation with Master table from 2 tables
Assume I have 3 tables like below
Master table - 10 columns
Table A - 10 columns
Table B - 10 columns
My requirement:
Master table is having one of the column with value “Table A | Table B”. This tells from where we need to reconcile the data .
(it means reconcile the columns from either table A or B with Master table)
Condition:
reconcile Table A columns with master table columns first . if it is null, then only reconcile with Table B

If I digest correctly, we have these examples of tables and values. The relevant columns are str1 (value to be reconciled) and str2 (table name, "Table A|Table B")
┌────────────────┐          ┌──────────────────┐        ┌───────────────────────┐
│  Table A       │          │  Table B         │        │   Master              │
├───────┬────────┤          ├───────┬──────────┤        ├──────┬─────────┬──────┤
│ str1  │ 9 cols │          │ str1  │  9 cols  │        │str1  │ str2    │8 cols│
┼───────┼────────┤          ├───────┼──────────┤        ├──────┼─────────┼──────┤
│ a1    │  ...   │          │ b2    │  ...     │        │ a1   │ aa      │  ... │
│       │        │          │       │          │        │ a3   │ aa      │      │
│ a3    │        │          │ b4    │          │        │ a5   │ aa      │      │
│       │        │          │       │          │        │ b2   │ bb      │      │
│ a5    │        │          │ b6    │          │        │ b4   │ bb      │      │
│       │        │          │       │          │        │ b6   │ bb      │      │
└───────┴────────┘          └───────┴──────────┘        └──────┴─────────┴──────┘

From table A perspective, we want to add/reconcile missing value(s). First, we look at master table to find the missing value(s) :
select aa.str1 as tbl_a_str1, mstr.str1 as mstr_str1, mstr.str2 as mstr_str2 from aa, mstr
where aa.str1(+) = mstr.str1

┌─────────┬────────────┐                                     
│ Table A │   Master   │                                     
├─────────┼─────┬──────┤                                     
│  str1   │ str1│ str2 │                                     
│         │     │      │                                     
│   a1    │  a1 │  aa  │                                     
│   a3    │  a3 │  aa  │                                     
│   a5    │  a5 │  aa  │                                     
│         │  b2 │  bb  │                                     
│         │  b4 │  bb  │                                     
│         │  b6 │  bb  │                                     
│         │     │      │                                     
└─────────┴─────┴──────┘ 

The missing values are b2, b4, and b6.
Option 1:reconcile with master data only
INSERT INTO aa
    (SELECT str1
       FROM mstr
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
                (SELECT str1
                   FROM aa
                  WHERE aa.str1 = mstr.str1));

Option 2:reconcile with specified table on Master.str2 column (in our example, table B)
DECLARE
    sql_query   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
    FOR arec IN (SELECT str1 AS col_name, str2 AS table_name
                   FROM mstr
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS
                            (SELECT str1
                               FROM aa
                              WHERE aa.str1 = mstr.str1))
    LOOP
        sql_query :=
               'INSERT INTO aa (SELECT str1 FROM '
            || arec.table_name
            || ' WHERE str1='''
            || arec.col_name
            || ''')';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query;
    END LOOP;
END;
/

Note:the query/script are not tuned for performance. There is also limitation on the dynamic query using execute immediate, where we cannot use bind argument for table name (refer to How to use execute immediate with variable table name and condition)
